# Dirichlet problem and its gradient norm

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ de a domain bounded and $v \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ solution of $\Delta v = -2$ in $\Omega$ and $v = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$.
Show that $u = |\nabla v|^2$ reaches its maximum in $\partial \Omega$.

**Motivation:** I'm curious to know how to solve it, because if we think about the line case, when taking a function $f$ in an open interval such that $f''< 0$, we have that this function is concave and, consequently, $f'$ is non-increasing. Hence, the maximum of $f'$ is at the boundary of this interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We calculate \begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} &= \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i} \sum_{k=1}^2 \bigg ( \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_k} \bigg )^2 \\
&= 2 \sum_{k=1}^2 \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_k}  \cdot \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x_k\partial x_i} 
\end{align*} and \begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2} &= 2 \sum_{k=1}^2 \bigg [ \bigg (\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x_k\partial x_i} \bigg )^2 +\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_k}  \cdot \frac{\partial^3 v}{\partial x_k\partial x_i^2}\bigg ]\\
&\geqslant 2 \sum_{k=1}^2 \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_k}  \cdot \frac{\partial^3 v}{\partial x_k\partial x_i^2}
\end{align*} It follows that $$ \Delta u \geqslant 2 \sum_{k=1}^2 \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_k} \cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial x_k} \Delta v =0 $$ since $\Delta v$ is constant. Hence, $u$ is subharmonic. Then the maximum principle implies $u$ attains its maximum on the boundary.

*Note that this argument requires $v \in C^3(\Omega)$. This is not a big deal since standard regularity theory implies that $v$ is in fact smooth in $\Omega$.